# Name for line segment parallel to triangle base

Tags: geometry, terminology, triangles

In describing an elegant construction of a regular pentagon, i'm struggling to find a nice way of describing the following:

A line segment starting at a point partway up one side of a (in this case, but not necessarily, equilateral) triangle, finishing at a point partway up another side, and parallel to the third side (the base).

In other words this line forms the base of a smaller similar triangle which shares an angle with the main triangle.

Is there a name for such a line?

Comment: Something like "draw a paralel to one side that intersect both other side"?

Comment: Yes, not just intersect but start and finish on those other sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it starts halfway, it's called midline, I think... Else, its just a parallel I suppose.

Comment: In this case it is the halfway line, so midline may well fit the bill - but i'm also interested in the more general case

Comment: Your suggestion of midline was right on the money. Looks like a synonym for it is mid-segment, and that the general case could be called a parallel segment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest  *ray included scaled parallel* with respect to common vertex point O ?